# ReactJS 0.9+ Code Coverage with ES2015 class keyword

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a basic demo app that I've put together and I have successfully been able to write test and get code coverage working.

Except for one minor problem.

All of the code that use the class keyword from ES2015 end up emitting code at the top that looks like this:

```
/*istanbul ignore next*/'use strict';Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });var _createClass = function () {function defineProperties(target, props) {for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {var descriptor = props[i];descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;descriptor.configurable = true;if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);}}return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);return Constructor;};}();var /*istanbul ignore next*/_react = require('react'); /*istanbul ignore next*/var React = _interopRequireWildcard(_react);
```

It is a very long line, I'll save you the trouble of reading it.

There are a couple of problems.

First, the /*istanbul ignore next*/ should be /* istanbul ignore next */ with a space before and after the comment, otherwise istanbul basically ignores it.

Second, even once you fix that, which I tried doing, there are functions in that string that don't get commented at all with the ignore comment.  I'm assuming because the set of functions all get added at once so only one comment gets applied at the beginning.

My configuration for babel, both in package.json and .babelrc looks like this:

```
"presets": ["react","es2015"],
"comments": true,
"compact": false
```

I've also tried adding babel-plugin-transform-runtime as

```
"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
```

both before and after the "presets" line but when I do that, I get errors that indicate the auto mocking is unable to read the metadata.

So, I guess the question is.  Does code coverage with the class keyword work at all in Jest?  If so, what am I missing?  Is there some way of getting transform-runtime working?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here in the future, I've figured this out using a combination of:

- The tranform-runtime plugin
- Modifying babel-jest

It takes 1000 words to describe the specifics, you can check it out here:

https://davembush.github.io/es2015-code-coverage-and-jest-react-js-unit-testing/